# How to restrict Postfix to accept local email delivery only for specific external email addresses

Tags: email, postfix

I have an email system usign postfix where all local UserIds have a different "official" email address in the format "*firstname.lastname@domain.com*".
Using virtual users or aliases, I can properly redirect all these "firstname.lastname@domain.com" to the proper local "userid" address...

However, how can I prevent email delivery sent directly to "*userid@domain.com*" from the outside?
Obviously, I need to keep the local delivery of emails to the actual userids (after it went thru the virtual users or aliases translation), but I don't want emails originating from the *outside* to be delivered directly to the userids. I would like to redirect all these external emails sent directly to "*userid@domain.com*" to another "catch all" alias..

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Using the following syntax in either the virtual user file or in the aliases file does not work:
   firstname.lastname@domain.com       userid
   userid@domain.com                            catchall_for_userids
because it sends all emails to the "catchall_for_userids" address (no local email delivery to the real users for their correct external email addresses...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) with `check_recipient_access` to write a restriction that prevents submissions through SMTP to `userid@domain.com`.

Maybe something like this:

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
```

`/etc/postfix/recipient_access`:

```
userid@domain.com  REJECT
```

Comment: The "REJECT" option in the "recipient_access" table doesn't allow me to send to a catchall_for_userids, but using the "REDIRECT" option in the "recipient_access" table does!
Thank you!